# javascript - Make all fields on a form required

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I want to be able to loop through all the fields on a form and make them required in a bit of javascript. I have been able to do a similar thing to make them disabled and have retrieved them all with `var controls = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get();`, but I know to set requirement level I need to get the attribute rather than the UI control, how can get get all attributes at once so I can loop through them?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copied almost exactly from the [CRM SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334409.aspx#BKMK_setRequiredLevel):

```
function MakeAllAttributesRequired() {
    var attributes = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get();
    for (var i in attributes) {
        attributes[i].setRequiredLevel("required");
    }
}
```